# Is there a way to disaggregate columns after pivoting a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pivot, hierarchical-data

my question is how to disaggregate hierarchical columns.
After merging two dataframes and computing some aggregations, I have a pivot table as a result. 
However, I want to **further extract the minimum time_delta in absolute terms per row as an additional column**. 
I am unable to do this, as python only extracts the minimum from the whole dataframe. 
I want following columns: index, name, firm_ID, timestamp_one, department_ID1, department_ID2, department_ID3, … and so on. I am aware that the number of columns in my dataframe depends on how many department_IDs a firm has. Basically, I am trying to merge top level column names with lower-level column names.

Thanks in advance

See my code below:

```
gp_columns = {
'name': ['companyA', 'companyB'],
'firm_ID' : [1, 2],
'timestamp_one' : ['2016-04-01', '2017-09-01']
}

fund_columns = {
    'firm_ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'department_ID' : [10, 11, 20, 21, 22],
    'timestamp_mult' : ['2015-01-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-10-01', '2017-02-01', '2018-11-01'],
    'number' : [400, 500, 1000, 3000, 4000]
    }

gp_df = pd.DataFrame(gp_columns)
fund_df = pd.DataFrame(fund_columns)
gp_df['timestamp_one'] = pd.to_datetime(gp_df['timestamp_one'])
fund_df['timestamp_mult'] = pd.to_datetime(fund_df['timestamp_mult'])

merged_df = gp_df.merge(fund_df)
merged_df

merged_df_v1 = merged_df.copy()
merged_df_v1['incidence_num'] = merged_df.groupby('firm_ID')['department_ID']\
                              .transform('cumcount')
merged_df_v1['incidence_num'] = merged_df_v1['incidence_num'] + 1
merged_df_v1['time_delta'] = merged_df_v1['timestamp_mult'] - merged_df_v1['timestamp_one']

merged_wide = pd.pivot(merged_df_v1, index = ['name','firm_ID', 'timestamp_one'], \
                       columns = 'incidence_num', \
                       values = ['department_ID', 'time_delta', 'timestamp_mult', 'number'])
merged_wide.reset_index()
```

[image: This is my result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.min()` takes an argument for `axis` that you can set to 1 for columns.

So try:

```py
merged_wide = merged_wide.reset_index() # might want this line at the end of what you have
merged_wide['timestamp_min'] = merged_wide['timestamp_mult'].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you mate. As you might have guessed, I am still a basic learner. Although this solves this particular issue, do you know if there is a possibility to merge the hierarchical columns?

Comment: if this answered your question, you should mark it answered / vote it as such so others know. regarding merge hierarchical columns, here is the pandas docs on multindex / hierarchical columns. you may also want to ask that specific question as well if you can't figure it out from the docs